# Compare values of specific keys in 2 different dictionaries to see if they are equal

Tags: python, dictionary, key, compare, typeerror

I am trying to see if the values of specific keys in 2 different dictionaries are equal (which they are at certain times).  If so, I want to print both dictionary values.  If not, I only want to print the dict2 values.  It should be noted that the keys are two different strings, but I only want to compare the values of those specific keys.

---

General idea of code

```
for key1,val in enumerate(dict1):
    KEY1printed=False
    for key2,val in enumerate(dict2):
        if dict1['key1'][val] == dict2['key2'][val]:
            if KEY1printed == False:
                print dict2['key2'][val], dict1['key1'][val]
                KEY1printed=True
            else:
                print dict2['key2'][val]
```

---

I get a "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" on the if dict1['key'][val] == dict2['key'][val].  However, earlier in the code I append val to the dictionary keys as integers (see code example below).  I'm not sure what to do about the problem.  Any suggestions?

---

Code example of val append

```
for line in indocument:
    val=line.split(",")
    dict1['key1'].append(int(val[2]))
    dict2['key2'].append(int(val[0]))
```

---

I have been having issues with types, because the microsoft excel 2010 program won't save the cell format when I change it from general to number.  When I open the file in openoffice, the cell format saves, but there are too many rows in my file, so I have to split my document.  I don't mind having to do this, but I think it might be messing with my python code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dict['key']`? (without the indexing by val)

Comment: Also, `key1` and `key2` are variables or strings? What type should the key be?

Comment: The keys within the 2 dictionaries are different strings (ex/ 'key1' and 'key2').  If I say "if dict1['key1']==dict2['key2']:", wouldn't they never be equal because the strings of the keys are different?  Maybe I just don't understand how dictionaries work.  I want to see if the values (val) of those two different keys ('key1', 'key2') in the 2 different dictionaries are equal.

Comment: No, that would work, `dict['key1']` would output just the value. It's indexed by the string, just as if you have a normal array indexed by numbers, `array[0]` would just output the value at position 0.

Comment: Okay.  I see what you mean.  Attached to each key is a list not a value.  Sorry about that.  How do I get it to compare each list within the keys of the 2 dictionary?

Comment: It's not a list attached to each key, it is indeed a value, you just don't need to index by it. `dict[key1] == dict[key2]` should work I think...